# Exclude specific post from displaying

Tags: php

I am trying to exclude a specific post ID from displaying. I've included the post ID as a `post__not_in` but being given an error I am unsure of, any obvious changes needed here?

```
                    <?php
                    // Create a variable to hold our custom Loop results
                    $frontpageposts = get_posts( array( 
                         'numberposts' => 1, // only the 3 latest posts
                         'post__not_in' => '-4135'
                    ) );

                    // Create output only if we have results
                    // Customize to suit your HTML markup
                    if ( $frontpageposts ) { 

                         foreach ( $frontpageposts as $fppost ) { 
                              // setup postdata, so we can use template tags
                              setup_postdata($fppost);
                              ?>

                              <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                   <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php //the_title(); ?>Latest News #1</a></h4>
                                   <div class="post-entry">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <?php //the_excerpt(); ?>
                                   </div>
                              </div>

                    <?php }
                    } 
                    ?>
```

**Error**

> Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /var/www/vhosts/testdomain.co.uk/faiauto/wp-includes/query.php on line 2451
>
> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/vhosts/testdomain.co.uk/faiauto/wp-includes/query.php on line 2451

Comment: `post__not_in` takes `array()` not `string`

Answer (score 1):

Post__not_in doesn't need the minus or the ' '
Make it an array like this:

```
'post__not_in' => array(4135),
```

Try adding the post ID into a variable e.g.

```
$excludes  = array('4135');

'post__not_in' => $excludes
```

Comment: So far, same error.

Comment: Oh I got rid of the error with: post_not_in => array(4135) but that specific post is still displaying.

Comment: @wharfdale are you sure about the post ID?

Comment: Yep, see here the ID from the url of me editing that post: /wp-admin/post.php?post=4135

Comment: @GarethGillman `post__not_in` accepts an array, not a string. You are however correct on the minus sign

Comment: @wharfdale have a look at my edit

Comment: I just tried with Brad Dalton's answer and that works, however I am still curious to see why your answer for me so far is not working. Am currently using your Variable method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your functions.php file and change the post I.D you want to exclude.

```
function wpsites_exclude_single_posts_home($query) {
if ($query->is_home() AND $query->is_main_query()) {
$query->set('post__not_in', array('007'));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_exclude_single_posts_home');
```

Change the [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) conditional tag if needed.

Source: [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Single_Posts_by_I.D_From_Home_Page)